# POCO C++ SAX parser: If the xml document encoding is ANSI then next statement is not reading and throwing encoding error exception

Tags: c++, libraries, poco

Suppose the following is the xml document then hello tag is not reading by the poco sax parser because of encoding is ANSI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ANSI"?>
<hello xmlns="  ">
```

If the encoding is UTF-8 then hello tag is reading and everything is went fine.

Is there any solution in POCO for this issue?

Comment: MSalters answer should be accepted, it's not an issue of POCO.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a POCO problem, fix the producer. There's no such thing as "ANSI" encoding in XML. The producer should generate output in a valid encoding. Whether that's "UTF-8" or "ISO-8859-1" doesn't really matter, as long as it's all consistent.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding problem arise if you specify a encoding but you use a different encoding, source of trouble could arise (in example) if you copy-paste a XML source between multiple documents, from webpages, or simply because it has a buggy encoder. Try to use some program that can detect encoding and change that, set it to UTF8 and then replace the header tag for ANSI wich the one for UTF8.

Comment: Copy-pasting should actually work. The Windows clipboard stores encodings, and Windows will transcode for applications. Of course, if a buggy program puts UTF-8 text on the clipboard and says it's ISO-8859-1, then things will still break. (I'm not sure if Linux is that smart, I've noticed that X Windows has a pretty rotten copy-paste implementation).